# Кто знаком с phpQuery?

Tags: php

Есть много одинаковых классов, и она все парсятся нормально, выходит 100 классов, но когда я с этих классов парсю href то парсит только только самый первый, почему не все?

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($html);
$elem = $doc->find('.ubernov')$elem->attr('href');

Comment: А потому что логично. Ищи какой-нибудь map.

Comment: Или обходить с foreach.